# How to use a DateTime to find the closest Date to it in an array of DateTimes with js or jq?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.)  Array  Explanation
Let's say for  example I have an array  with several Dates like:

[01.April.2021 00:03:49, 01.May.2021 00:01:21, ...]

2.) Closest Date Explanation 1
And I have a findDate which equals 17.April.2021 00:08:12.

--> I would like my Method to return me in this  case the 01.May.2021 00:01:21

3.) Closest  Date Explanation 2
or lets  say I have a findDate which euqals 08.March.2021 00:07:13

--> In  this  case i  would  like  my  method to return me 01.April.2021 00:03:49

--What I  tried:

- Wrote  myself  amethod which checks  distances and returns smaller  distance -doesn't  work  as it  should
- Used an Sort function, still didn't work

Some Code of the sort function, please keep in Mind i  may  be totally  wrong with this  sort function:

```
//dates are sorted as Date Objects  (NOT strings)
function getClosestDateInDateArrByFindDate(dateArr, findDate) { //returns sorted array of dates

var resultdates = dateArr.sort(function (a, b) {
var distancea = Math.abs(findDate - a);
var distanceb = Math.abs(findDate - b);

//1st return  try
return new Date(distancea - distanceb);

//2nd return try
if (distancea > distanceb) {
    return a;
else {
    return b;
});
}
return resultDates; //or  resultDates[0] cause resultDates[0] features the smallest distance  to  findDate
```

Anyone has an Idea or maybe sometime implemented an method like this?
Regards.

Comment: The custom sorting function should return a tristate, -1, 0 or 1, not the arguments.

Comment: just convert all dates in milliseconds and then sort the array, and chose the closest date, and then convert it back in normal date format

Comment: @AmAnKumAr Yeah I do know the rough logic behind it, but how would  you put that to code?

Comment: @unstuckMe `return distancea - distanceb` should do the trick.

Comment: Noup. That was my first try, didn't do the trick sadyl :-/